# How to make requirejs to work with jasmine and blanketjs for code coverage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, jasmine, blanket.js

I was working on generating code coverage report using blanketjs.
Click [here](http://adamish.com/lab/jasmine-requirejs-blanket/spec-runner.html?catch=false) .

But I am finding difficulty in achieving the same.

Here's my code :
`require(['jquery', 'boot', 'JasmineBlanket'], function ($, boot, blanket) {
blanket.options('filter', 'js/');
        // exclude filter
        blanket.options('antifilter', [ 'js/third-party', '../test/spec/', 'js/text.js' ]);
        blanket.options('branchTracking', true); 
        var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
        jasmineEnv.addReporter(new jasmine.BlanketReporter());
        jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;
        // Define all of your specs here. These are RequireJS modules.
        var specs = [
          'operatorscreentests/CanvasToolsTests',
          'operatorscreentests/SmoothingTests',
          'operatorscreentests/UIToolsTests'
        ];
        $(document).ready(function() {
          require(specs, function(spec) {
            window.onload();
          });
});`

I am getting undefined for blanket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these things from above code to make it work :
Code : 

`blanket.options('filter', 'js/');
        // exclude filter
        blanket.options('antifilter', [ 'js/third-party', '../test/spec/', 'js/text.js' ]);
        blanket.options('branchTracking', true);`

Remove above things and you are ready to go. 
Basically in HtmlReporter you have already added the reporter as blanket by using `jasmineEnv.addReporter(new jasmine.BlanketReporter());` which is enough.

Let me know if it works.